# Grails :native2ascii error when i run dummy application

Tags: grails, groovy, ggts

when i used to run the dummy application on grails in ggts(groovy&grails tool suite) its showing error like this :

Error packaging application: Error occurred processing message bundles: Error starting Sun's native2ascii:  (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: What versions of Grails, GGTS and JDK are you using?

Comment: Also add the used JDK for good measure

Comment: grails : 2.3.7 , ggts-3.6.4.RELEASE , jdk 1.7.0